# A problem related to series that looks similar to Puiseux series

Tags: real-analysis

I was doing some research and stumbled upon series of the form $$f(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{+ \infty}a_l \cdot (g(x))^{\frac {1}{l}}$$

A function $g(x)$ in my research is infinitely many times differentiable but $f(x)$ is discontinuos (although not wildly) and I am not sure can this happen at all?

> That is, can a discontinuos $f(x)$ be developed into this kind of series at all if $g(x)$ is infinitely many times differentiable?

More precisely, $f$ has an infinite number of discontinuities and a set of discontinuities is nowhere dense.

Also, $g$ is strictly increasing function.

Comment: In what sense do you have that $f$ is an infinite sum? There must be some topology behind this (e.g is it point-wise convergence, $L^1$ or $L^2$ convergence? uniform convergence? etc).

Comment: Can you give some more details about what your functions $f$ and $g$ are?

Comment: I am still not sure, what you want to know exactly, but you may want to take a look at Fourier-series, although they are of a different form. However, they show how to obtain a discontinuous function as an infinite sum of continuous functions

Comment: @R.J.Etienne Fourier series are really of a different form, how would I apply them here?

Comment: What I mean is that if your coefficients $a_l$ fulfil certain conditions, this may result in a series that is comparable to a Fourier-series, the answer to your question could be affirmative. I may be able to construct such a sequence, but not right now and not with a more precise knowledge of your functions. Maybe you can come up with something yourself.